# How to get the group differences after Bonferroni correction in multiple comparison?

Tags: r, anova, post-hoc, bonferroni, tukey-hsd-test

After an ANOVA in R, do you know if it is possible to get the group differences using Bonferroni correction ?

If I use the iris dataset

```
a<-aov(iris$Sepal.Width~iris$Species, data=iris)
```

When I run a TukeyHSD, I get the group differences directly

```
TukeyHSD(a)
  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = iris$Sepal.Width ~ iris$Species, data = iris)

$`iris$Species`
                       diff         lwr        upr     p adj
versicolor-setosa    -0.658 -0.81885528 -0.4971447 0.0000000
virginica-setosa     -0.454 -0.61485528 -0.2931447 0.0000000
virginica-versicolor  0.204  0.04314472  0.3648553 0.0087802
```

However, with Bonferroni, the only function I have found is pairwise.t.test() which returns the pvalue but not the interval estimates.

```
pairwise.t.test(iris$Sepal.Width,iris$Species, p.adj = "bonf")

    Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 

data:  iris$Sepal.Width and iris$Species 

           setosa               versicolor
versicolor < 0.0000000000000002 -         
virginica  0.0000000014         0.0094    

P value adjustment method: bonferroni
```

Is there a way to get these interval estimates with other corrections than Tukey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the `emmeans` package, which allows easy working with contrasts.
We can get specify a bonferroni-adjusted pairwise series of tests by

```
fit <- aov(Sepal.Width ~ Species, data = iris)

fit_em_bonf <- emmeans::emmeans(
  fit,
  specs  = pairwise ~ Species,
  adjust = "bonf"
)
```

and then extract confidence intervals from the resulting object as usual

```
confint(fit_em_bonf, level = 0.95)
```

This produces

```
$emmeans
 Species    emmean    SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 setosa       3.43 0.048 147     3.33     3.52
 versicolor   2.77 0.048 147     2.68     2.86
 virginica    2.97 0.048 147     2.88     3.07

Confidence level used: 0.95 

$contrasts
 contrast               estimate     SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 setosa - versicolor       0.658 0.0679 147    0.493   0.8225
 setosa - virginica        0.454 0.0679 147    0.289   0.6185
 versicolor - virginica   -0.204 0.0679 147   -0.369  -0.0395

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Conf-level adjustment: bonferroni method for 3 estimates
```

from which you can read off the confidence intervals for the pairwise difference contrasts.